# urllib.request page larger than memory

Tags: python, urllib

Is there a way to process a stream of data from urllib.request.urlopen(req) so that it can be processed in chuncks?

I have a limited size machine and am pulling an API call that is potentially larger than the memory size on my machine and is causing out of memory exceptions.

I am currently performing the following command:

```
resp = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode())
```

Comment: have you tried processing line by line as opposed to chunk by chunk?

Comment: I am not sure how I would do that? When I look at the .read() output, it is a giant string, that I am converting into a dictionary with json.loads()

Answer (score 0):

Try processing it line by line which may lower the mem size.

```
req = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = ''
for line in req:
     line = line.decode()
     data += line
data = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: This does not work because req comes back as a single line, which means on the first itteration we are pulling the full value.

Comment: @user3554796 it would be great if you could supply exactly what req points to like the url so I can be of better service.